# Start Java Desktop app and get rid of Commander

Tags: java, windows

I need to startup a Java Desktop application and I'd like to get rid of the **Windows 8** Commander console. So I've tried with:

```
start "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw" com.mypackage.MainFrame
```

However, by including "start" at the beginning results in an error:

> Cannot find file `com.mypackage.MainFrame`

By removing the "start" command, the Desktop application starts correctly but the user needs to manually close the Commander window.

Any idea how to get rid of the Commander window?

Comment: create .bat file and write your all commands to start the app in that.

Comment: Already tried. Wrapping the commands in a .bat and using start to launch the batch file results in the caller window to disappear but the (callee) console still up.

Comment: Jar applications with correct Manifest can simply be double-clicked to start. Windows users will not mind.

Comment: Sorry but I need to start as a batch file. Need to execute some commands before launching the JVM

Comment: use `exit` command at the end of your .bat file

Comment: doesn't work either. Pls provide a reason for downvoting the question and, if you are that smart, provide a link or solution as well.

Comment: I agree with you. +1 for you. Most of the hack mentioned are just not available on Windows 8, that's why I think it's an intesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to pass double quotes to hack the start command. So, use the following to start your application:

```
start "" "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw" com.mypackage.MainFrame
```